# getitem localstorage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to setup active item cookie for menu.

So I used local storage for this task. When a menu item is active , It is stored in local storage like this-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.nav-pills>li').click(function () {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                var activeIndex = $(this).index();
                alert("Before pageload active item is "+ activeIndex);
                localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', activeIndex);

            });
        });

    </script>
```

and menu looks like-

[image]

and then I set this active item on window load-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue');
            alert("After pageload active item is " + activeIndex);

            $('.nav-pills li:nth-child("' + activeIndex + '")').addClass('active');

        });

    </script>
```

menu now-

[image]

Here you can see from both the images that active menu's index is still the last index before page load. But this is not applying that `.active` class on this menu item.

How can I set this menu item active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
$('.nav-pills li:nth-child("' + activeIndex + '")').addClass('active');
```

to this

```
$('.nav-pills li:eq("' + activeIndex + '")').addClass('active');
```

or remove double quotes

```
 $('.nav-pills li:nth-child(' + activeIndex + ')').addClass('active');
```

but the nth-child is 1 based index where as eq is zero based index

Check http://jsfiddle.net/HLUB9/2/